domtoimage.toBlob() not working in production
i'm trying to use the WebShare API so that my users can share images of their teams on my website. What I do is that i use dom-to-image to generate Blob and then a file and use navigator.share to let my users share the images.
This is my code
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
  const shareTeamButton = document.querySelector('.share-team-button') || false;

  if (shareTeamButton) {

    const teamPreviewDiv = document.querySelector('#teamPreview');
    const shareBand = document.querySelector(".share-team-socials-container");
    const shareTeamBtn = document.querySelector(".share-team-btn");
    shareTeam();
    shareTeamButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      teamPreviewDiv.style.bottom = "0px";
      shareBand.style.display = "flex";
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

    });

    function shareTeam() {
      const elementToCapture = document.querySelector(".share-team-container");
      // Ensure this ID matches the element you want to capture
      shareTeamBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.log("clicked button");

        if (elementToCapture) {
          console.log("there is an element to capture");
          domtoimage.toBlob(elementToCapture).then(blob => {
            console.log("Blob created", blob);
            const file = new File([blob], "team_preview.png", { type: "image/png" });
            navigator.share({
                files: [file],
                title: 'Check out my team!',
                text: 'Just created this awesome team. Have a look!'
            }).then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
            .catch((error) => console.error('Sharing failed', error));
          }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error taking screenshot with dom-to-image:', error);
            console.log("Document clone error:", error.message);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Element to capture not found. Please check the ID and element's existence in the DOM.");
        }
      })
    }
  }
});

Locally the blob is created perfectly fine.
These are my logs that prove it
(https://i.sstatic.net/YWUl5.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/YWUl5.png)
But in production, the blob isn't created and therefore there is no image to share.
These are my logs in production

Does anyone know why this is happening?

how do you recover domtoimage ? if you display it what is it containing in production ?

I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question.

you don't show us how domtoimage is filled ?

What do you mean by filled?

where and how do you declare the variable domtoimage ?

"in production, the blob isn't created". What's the difference in console.log output, are there any errors reported on the console, and what code path must be taken in production for no errors to be reported?

There are no errors reported on the console. And for the console.log, in production, nothing is logged in the console after the message that confirms that the element that i'm targeting with domtoimage.toBlob is indeed present and loaded. As for your third question, i didn't understand it.

The only explanation I can think of to explain the production issue is that the promise returned by domtoimage.toBlob remains pending. Try assigning the return value to a variable (e.g. blobPromise), log it to the console, and only then add then and catch clauses to blobPromise.  Now what does the log say about the state  blobPromise is in ?

Promise {status: "pending"}
Exactly what you were  thinking. No errors are logged on to the console.
Do you have any idea as to how i can solve this?

Great, so now you know what the problem is. Although I have no idea what is causing the promise to remain pending, I suggest logging the argument passed to it both locally and in production and compare the results. For complete paranoia log the value of domtoimage.toBlob in both cases to confirm it's the same code. Paranoia is good in this situation.

The issue is due to CORS errors because in the code i try to turn into a canvas and then a blob, there are images that i get from Cloudinary, the cloud based image management service I use. I will send the full solution when I have it. Thanks for the help @traktor.

Good to hear you're making progress, I was starting to think it was due to a tainted canvas (because of CORS). I look forward to upvoting your answer to your own question - courage!
